# Альтернатива System.getProperty("user.name") для JavaScript

Tags: javascript, active-directory

В Java приложении с помощью `System.getProperty("user.name");` можно получить имя пользователя, под которым зашли на комп. Есть ли аналогичная возможность на JavaScript в браузере получить логин пользователя, как это делает Java?

Может есть возможность сделать это через Active Directory? Чтоб можно было получить именно в браузере имя.

Comment: Очень надеюсь, что нет. Мне не хотелось бы, чтобы любой сайт знал точно мои персональные данные без моего на то **явного** согласия.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518092/javascript-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-user

Comment: я думаю, что даже не все ОС имеют такое понятие, как *имя пользователя* для входа. Например, в Android используется максимум имя поумолчанию. А на Android тоже есть браузер, как ни странно

Comment: Ребят помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос)))
У меня есть корпоративная сеть, код для работы с Active Directory  я смог написать (получить имя, мыло могу). Но поиск в AD осуществляется по такому фильтру как имя пользователя. И получается дилемма, коллеги будут юзать только веб-сервис, соответственно мне как-то нужно получить это имя пользователя, но как? Или может можно как-то с помощью сервлета и Active Directory получить пользователя? Или может сам JavaScript умеет работать с Active Directory?

Comment: `<script type='text/javascript'>
java.lang.System.getProperty()
</script>`
не подходит?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, вы не путаете Java и JavaScript?

Comment: Не работает такой код. Это ведь java код в коде js?

Comment: Ваши пользователи настолько ленивы, что не могут вбить свою доменную учетную запись для входа в web приложение?

Comment: Не в этом деле.
раньше это веб приложение было написано на C# и прежний разработчик каким-то магическим образом получал имя пользователя текущего компа. А я на java не могу сделать это((

Comment: Вы тоже можете - через ActiveX. Но работать это будет только в IE.

Comment: Как вариант, предыдущий разработчик прикрутил к приложению NTLM или Kerberos аутентификацию. Но это решение на бэкенде, на фронтенде это сделать не получится.

Comment: @fori1ton А Active Directory может помочь в решении этой проблемы?

Comment: А если я опубликую код на C# сможете помочь понять, как прежний разработчик решил эту задачу?

Comment: @Vorobey.A, Active Directory недоступен из браузерного JS, так что либо пишите код в бэкенде, либо смиритесь с невозможностью узнать имя пользователя ОС. ActiveX и Applet не предлагаю по причине их дырявости и постепенно отмирающей поддержки современными браузерами. Код на C#, который вы собрались публиковать, работает на сервере, посему имеет больше возможностей выбить из пользователя имя, под которым он залогинен (посредством того же NTLM).

Comment: @fori1ton отлично) Active Directory у меня отлично работает на сервере Тогда возникает вопрос, коллега сделал какие-то изменения в веб-сервисе, как мне на бэкенде понять что за пользователь сделал такие изменения?

Comment: @Vorobey.A, если у вас возник новый вопрос, оформите его как отдельный (простите за тавтологию) вопрос, а этот закройте. Тем более, ответ на изначальный вопрос вы получили.

Comment: @fori1ton как закрыть этот вопрос?